# How to auto-change all new .webloc files' icons to web page favicon?

Tags: safari, automator, icon, desktop, web-browser

I'd love to have all website URL files on the desktop take the favicon of the corresponding web page, rather than the Safari icon.

This would mimic the function of adding a page to the home screen of iOS.

How can I set something up, perhaps in Automator, so that, when I drag a new URL from Chrome to the desktop, the page's favicon is fetched and applied as the icon image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Disclaimer**: This answer is being presented strictly as a *proof of concept* in that it has had limited testing, *shell script* contains limited *error handling*, and requires the use of a third-party *shell script* to apply the **favicon** to the **.webloc** *file(s)*.

---

Note that the third-party *shell script* is making use of native **macOS** utilities so it should inherently be safe to use. I did review the *code* within the third-party *shell script* and felt comfortable using it as I saw nothing ominous within.

Third-party *shell script*: [**fileicon**](https://github.com/mklement0/fileicon#manual-installation) -- I used the manual installation instructions on the linked web page.

---

That said, you would need to assign a **Folder Action** to the destination *folder* to which the **URL** dragged from the browser, or *file*, is dragged and dropped.

The **Folder Action** would then trigger e.g. a *shell script* that would extract the *domain name* from the **URL** within the **.webloc** *file* to then download an e.g. **.png** *file* of the website's **favicon** and then set it as the icon of the **.webloc** *file*.

Retrieving the **favicon** is done using `curl` and a **Google URL** designed for that.

You can use **Automator** to create a **Folder Action** *workflow* using a **Run Shell Script** *action*, with settings as shown in the image further below.

Replace the default *code* in the **Run Shell Script** *action* with the following *example* **shell script** *code*:

```bash
for f in "$@"; do
    [ -f "${f}" ] || continue
    [[ ${f} =~ ^.*\.webloc$ ]] || continue
    domain="$(/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print :URL" "${f}" | awk -F '/' '{print $3}')"
    /usr/bin/curl "https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?sz=64&domain_url=${domain}" -o "/tmp/favicon.png"
    /usr/local/bin/fileicon set "${f}" "/tmp/favicon.png"
    [ -e "/tmp/favicon.png" ] && rm "/tmp/favicon.png"
done
```

---

[image: Automator Folder Action]

---

**Notes:**

What the *shell script code* in the **Run Shell Script** *action* is doing for each *item* dropped in the target *folder* that has the **Folder Action** set:

- Checks the *object* dropped is a *file*, or continues to the next *item* if more than one was dropped.
- Checks the *object* dropped ends with **.webloc**, or continues to the next *item* if more than one was dropped.
- The third line of *code* within the `for` *loop* sets the *value* of the `domain` *variable* to that which is between `//` and the following `/` in the **URL** of the **.webloc** *file*.
- Downloads the target website's **favicon** as a **.png** *file*.
- Set the downloaded **favicon.png** *file* as the icon for the **.webloc** *file* using the third-party `fileicon` *shell script*.
- Deletes the downloaded **favicon.png** *file*.

More about the `domain` *variable*:

Using a **.webloc** *file* created for this question, its contents is, e.g.:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>URL</key>
    <string>https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/411944/how-to-auto-change-all-new-webloc-files-icons-to-web-page-favicon</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

The `PlistBuddy -c "Print :URL" "${f}"` portion, of the *compound command*, returns:

```
https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/411944/how-to-auto-change-all-new-webloc-files-icons-to-web-page-favicon
```

Which is *piped* to `awk` and returns e.g. `apple.stackexchange.com`, and through *command substitution* `$(command)`, which allows the output of a *command* to replace the *command* itself, sets it as the *value* of the `domain` *variable* to then be used in the **URL** of the subsequent `curl` *command*.

More about the **URL** used in the `curl` *command*:

**Google** provides a method by which to retrieve a **.png** *file* of a website's **favicon** and as coded, it retrieves a 64 pixel size of the **favicon** as set in `sz=64` segment of the **Google URL**. This can be changed, however anything higher the `64` is probably going to be too blurred and would not look as nice.  Even `64` in some cases may be too blurred. If this becomes an issue set it to `32`, although by the nature of typical **favicon** *files*, which are `16x16` pixels, there will always be issues when increasing its size.

Removing the applied **favicon**:

If you do not like the **favicon** that was applied to the **.webloc** *file*, or just want to remove it, you can remove it from its **Get Info** *window* by selecting the target *file* in **Finder** and press **⌘I**, and then select the icon and press the <kbd>delete</kbd> *key*.

You can also, in **Terminal**, use `fileicon` to remove it, e.g.:

```
fileicon rm /path/to/filename.webloc
```

- The *command* above assume `fileicon` is within the `PATH` passed to the *shell*, otherwise use e.g.: `/path/to/fileicon`

Working with the **Folder Action** afterwards:

If after you have initially created and used the **Folder Action** and would like to edit/stop/start/remove the **Folder Action**, this can be done using the **Folder Action Setup** utility. Press **⌘Spacebar** to bring up **Spotlight** and start typing **Folder Action Setup** until it appears, which you can then press <kbd>enter</kbd>, or click it the list, to open it.

The **UI** of the **Folder Action Setup** utility should be self-explanatory and easy to use.